# how to search for an image in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hii,
how can i programmatically search for an image in iphone.
as i am developing the application like that which would browse for the image in iphone.

Comment: Do you wan't to browse the images stored on the iPhone? The ones you can browse with the Photos application? Or do you wan't to brows images only from your application? Please be more precise what exactly do you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the imaes stored in the photo library you can easily do it by using a UIImagePickerController.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html